# Node.js - Getting "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED" when testing express app with mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, express, mocha.js

First of all, I'm not listening on port 80 or 8080. I'm listening on port 1337.

I created a simple HTTP server using express. Here is the *app.js* script to start the server.

```
require('./lib/server').listen(1337)
```

The server script is located in `lib/server.js` file, since the same script will also be used in the test script.

```
var http = require('http')
,   express = require('express')
,   app = express()

app.get('/john', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello John!')
})

app.get('/sam', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello Sam!')
})

module.exports = http.createServer(app)
```

And, finally the `test/test.js`:

```
var server = require('../lib/server')
,   http = require('http')
,   assert = require('assert')

describe('Hello world', function(){

    before(function(done){
        server.listen(1337).on('listening', done)
    })

    after(function(){
        server.close()
    })

    it('Status code of /john should be 200', function(done){
        http.get('/john', function(res){
            assert(200, res.statusCode)
            done()
        })
    })

    it('Status code of /sam should be 200', function(done){
        http.get('/sam', function(res){
            assert(200, res.statusCode)
            done()
        })
    })

    it('/xxx should not exists', function(done){
        http.get('/xxx', function(res){
            assert(404, res.statusCode)
            done()
        })
    })

})
```

But I get a 3/3 errors:

```
Hello world
1) Status code of /john should be 200
2) Status code of /sam should be 200
3) /xxx should not exists


✖ 3 of 3 tests failed:

1) Hello world Status code of /john should be 200:
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)

2) Hello world Status code of /sam should be 200:
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)

3) Hello world /xxx should not exists:
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
```

I really don't understand why this, since my test script seems logic. I ran the server `node app.js` and tested manually, `localhost:1337/john` and `localhost:1337/sam` and it works great!

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to change the port number?

Comment: The problem remains the same, no matter what is the port (changed randomly several times).

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:1337/john` in your `http.get()`?

Comment: Thanks Amberlamps, giving the full path works well for all the tests. Can you add it as an answer in order to validate and close the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `http.get()` to work, you need to assign the full path to the resource as the first argument:

```
http.get('http://localhost:1337/john', function(res){
    assert(200, res.statusCode)
    done()
})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
http.get({path: '/john', port: 1337}, function(res){
    //...
});
```

Should work. http.get assumes port 80 if nothing else is specified.

Comment: He said it does not work no matter what port he is using. I am assuming that he tried it also with `80`.